# DataTables render return string is being escaped inside button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to pass a long string to a modal. Inside the dataTable creation i'm doing this.

```
render: function(data, type, row) {return '<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-id="'+row.IncidentID+'" data-journal="'+row.Journal+'" type="button" data-target="#myModal">'+"Details"+'</button>'} },
```

The problem is the row.journal in some cases that data is being escaped and shown in the button. In these cases clicking on the button doesn't launch the modal either. Just refreshes the page.

[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NrUE.png)

I'm using it this way to pass to a modal so i can retrieve the journal data.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log("in modal call");
    var triggerLink = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var journal = triggerLink.data("journal");
    var id = triggerLink.data("id");
    console.log(e.relatedTarget);
    console.log(journal);
    $("#modalTitle").text("Incident: " + id);
    $(this).find(".modal-body").html("<p> "+journal+"</p>");});});
```

Comment: The real terminology to use here is that row.Journal is "not escaped". You probably have double quotes and/or angle brackets in the value which is closing the button prematurely. So you need to "escape" the value in row.Journal. First print the value as it is, outside the button to see what exactly is being returned. Then escape, or replace the culprit characters accordingly.

Comment: Yes it is because of angle brackets. However is there a way to change this in the render function call? Without modifying the data in row.journal.

Comment: Look into "URL encode". The angle brackets will become &lt and &gt but appear as angle brackets on screen.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use encodeURIComponent() and decodeURIComponent() functions to solve this.